# Eclipse - Wicket - HTML files from dependent projects not being found

Tags: eclipse, wicket

I want to build a reusable Wicket component in Eclipse. I have one project "components" which have files such as MyComponent.java and MyComponent.html. Then I have a project "application" which contains my application code, from which I wish to use a MyComponent.

However, Wicket cannot find the MyComponent.html. If I copy this file from "components" to "application", and use exactly the same path, then Wicket finds it no problem.

I therefore summize that Eclipse is not copying the HTML file from the dependent project "components" and making it available to the web application. I cannot really confirm that as I don't know where the JAR is being generated from the "components" project, nor do I know where/if the WAR is being generated from the "application" project.

I have looked at the project settings in "components" and cannot find any option to explicitly publish HTML (non-Java) files when the project is being built; but I cannot find any option which is explicitly forbidding this either. In the "application" project I find no option to include HTML files from the other project (there is only the option to include the JAR - which potentially should be enough?)

**Update:** I am not using Maven, just using the default build process of Eclipse.

**Update:** I am using Tomcat within Eclipse (but without any Eclipse plug-in for Tomcat; it seems to work fine without it - only obviously that's not quite true hence my question...)

Comment: Ideally, as you suggest, the HTML from "components" should be included in the "components" jar file.  If you are using Maven to build your project (as many wicket projects use) then there is a place where you may have accidentally removed (or not added) the part about including HTML when building.  Check the Maven Wicket Quickstart for the proper settings perhaps?

Comment: OK thanks for the information! It's also good to know what approach I should generally be heading for, even if it isn't quite working yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Classic Eclipse action - for other reasons (restarting the project always resulted in a 404 for no apparent reason: I checked all the config files and everything seemed fine..), I deleted the "application" project from Eclipse and **re-created it**. Now everything works fine (HTML files are available...)

Answer (score 1):

Check Eclipse's source folders inclusion/exclusion filters. Project -> right button -> Properties -> Java Build path -> tab Source -> select Source Folder -> button Edit.

Comment: I expanded the source entry in the build path section, It says `Included: (All)` and `Excluded: (None)`. Is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Tomcat - during testing I normally use a Tomcat context to reference my Eclipse project workspace. 
The workspace contains a context/WEB-INF directory structure, into which all my compiled classes, properties, HTML and other resources are copied.
The Tomcat context file lives in the directory (Tomcat)/conf/Catalina/localhost and contains an entry of the following format:

```
<Context path="/mywebapp" docBase="C:/eclipse/workspace/myapp/context" reloadable="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! After some time doing research I had a solution!

You need to specify to maven that it needs to include all the files, the way how maven understand this is by adding the next command.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

It worked for me, I hope it works for any of you that have the same problem!
I guess for the person that posted this query its too late, but not for you that have this problem!